# How can i recreate my Partition Table

Tags: hard-drive, startup, disk-utility, partition, macos

**What happened:**

While i was tinkering around with my bootcamp partition something went terribly wrong. end of story is, i have no partitions left in my partition table

The current situation:
i can boot my mac into internet recovery but diskutil shows only one partition on my 500gb harddrive.

**the previous partitions were:**

1: mac partition - filevault (SHOULD BE RECOVERED):

was ~320 GB in size and the standard mac partition at the beginning, which got shrinked at the end to fit the bootcamp win partition (2). the mac partition uses filevault and runs as mentioned the yosemite public beta.

2: windows 8.1 bootcamp partition (CAN BE DELETED)

**the question:**

can i somehow recreate my partition table and make my mac partition bootable again?
if the windows partition is lost, so be it, as long the mac one is saved.

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) looks promising as i assume i have to somehow scan my harddrive for partitions and recreate the partition table manually.

How should i continue? if you need any additional information just ask!
thanks in advance for any help!

**UPDATE:**

this is what test disk says, which is exactly my partition scheme from before the mess-up. How should i proceed? rewrite the table to contain only EFI and the unknown "macintosh HD" which is the one to be saved?
[image: TestDisk output]

Comment: I suggest you to reorder your question to present partition states in chronological order.
It will be much clearer. At the same time, please provide the complete names of your 2 partitions so as to clearly name them within your problem description.

Comment: hope it is clearer now what the current situation is and what i try to achieve.

Comment: If you boot to internet recovery you could re-install a working Mac OS on to an external drive. That might be the simplest way to get you to a place where you can back up the Mac files. If not, you'll have to hope for expertise on tools to reconstruct a filesystem. Something like Disk Warrior or Data Rescue might be of use - search here for tips on those programs.

Comment: im currently creating a bootable osx mavericks stick and try to fix the table with TestDisk from there. I'll update the question if anything changes. thanks!

Comment: @bmike question was reworked to fit the rules

Comment: I wish you luck whether it's on topic or off. Are you just looking to recover some files and then patch things up? What does SHOULD BE RECOVERED mean to you in the context of running Mavericks going forward? (Also - seriously - no backups?)

Comment: With "should be recovered" i mean that the partition should be made bootable again, most likely by repairing my partitions table i guess. I do have file backups but no complete timeMachine backup.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i managed to boot my osx partition again.

To find the hidden partition i created a bootable OSX Mavericks installation on an external harddrive on which i installed TestDisk.

TestDisk scanned my builtin HDD for partitions and created the output seen in the question.

To restore the table gdisk with the given sectors gdisk was used.